# How to pass multipart request from one server to another in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data, multer

I have two nodeJS servers,
Server 1 gets requests from the client and passes it to server 2 which returns a response to server 1 and it responds to the client.
The client uploads a file and it has to be passed the same way as any other rest request that I have.

I use **axios** on server 1 to send the data to server2 and **multer** on server 2 to store the file on disk.

I have an issue sending the request from server1 to server2 because the body of the request contains nothing and the request is **Multipart**.
[image]

How should I handle the request on Server 1 ???

```
router.post('/fileUpload', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "Got file" });
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `form-data` module to send multipart/form-data from nodejs application

Here is the code you can implement on Server1 to receive image file from client and send it to Server2.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer')();
const FormData = require('form-data');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/fileUpload' , multer.single('fileFieldName'), (req , res) => {
    const fileRecievedFromClient = req.file; //File Object sent in 'fileFieldName' field in multipart/form-data
    console.log(req.file)

    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('fileFieldName', fileRecievedFromClient.buffer, fileRecievedFromClient.originalname);

    axios.post('http://server2url/fileUploadToServer2', form, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`
            }
        }).then((responseFromServer2) => {
            res.send("SUCCESS")
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.send("ERROR")
        })
})

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Here `multer` is used to handle the uploaded file

Comment: Very helpful! For conciseness, use: await axios.post('http://server2url/fileUploadToServer2', form, { headers: form.getHeaders() })

Answer (score 1):

```
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('query', updateDocQuery);
 formData.append('variables', JSON.stringify(this.setUpdateDocParams() || {}));
 for (let i = 0; i < fileArr.length; i++) {
            formData.append(`file${i}`, fileArr[i])
        }
```

you can append your query variables and file to formData and pass formData to body

Comment: I'm having an issue sending the `res.file` using **FormData** it sends a request but without the file, Is there any practical example on how to accomplish it? I was able to send file after reading it from the disk on the server1 using **fs.createReadStream**

Comment: if you able to read file from disk,then append that file to formData

Answer (score 0):

To complete Apar Adhikari's answer, I also realized what I needed to make this end to end process happen:

**html form file input->onsubmit event->client post file to svr 1->file in svr 1->file in svr 2**

was **reading** the file server-side as well, on server 1, using `fs.createReadStream(filepath)`, where `filepath` is the relative file path where I chose to upload my files to - on DISK for now, using Multer.

Only AFTER this file reading step, I appended `fs.createReadStream(filepath)` as a value in the formData object he called `form`, against the key my 3rd-party API located on server 2 will recognize.

So, basically, here is the journey that my file takes, once the `onsubmit` event has fired client-side, and the file been posted from client-side to server 1

```
require("dotenv").config()
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const FormData = require('form-data') // svr-side require for multipart/form-data encoding
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs') // required to call fs.createReadStream() - see below
const cors = require('cors')
const multer  = require('multer')
const axios = require('axios') // svr-side require for req to 3rd-party API


// Multer file storage options - I chose to store the file on DISK with the help of Multer, in a ./uploadFiles directory
const uploadedFilesFolderName = "uploadFiles"
const UPLOAD_DIR = `${__dirname}/${uploadedFilesFolderName}`
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, UPLOAD_DIR);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${file.originalname}`);
  },
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const app = express()
const PORT = // port of your choice here
//const PORT = process.env.PORT // to change used PORT
const API_URL = "https://my.apiurl.com/"

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static(UPLOAD_DIR)) // my ./uploadFiles dir

// serving index.html where the file input form is
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/index.html")
})

// my client->svr 1 post route
// in my HTML, the name of the file input field is 'fileInput'
// retrieved here with the help of upload.single('fileInput') arg
app.post('/upload-single-file', upload.single('fileInput'), async function (req, res, next) {
  try {

    // retrieving also text fields from the HTML form
    // (eg a file description, an option chosen by user via a drop-down...)
    const whateverTxt = req.body.whateverField // see multer doc for details on req.body

    const fileFromClient = req.file // see multer doc for details on req.file object
    
    //...

    const apiToken = // here the result of a login request or sth authenticating into my 3rd-party API
    // do whatever other prior async/await request with axios here

    //...
    
    // 1. Build the filepath where the file retrieved from client-side has "landed" (my ./uploadFiles dir)
    let uploadedFilePath = `./${uploadedFilesFolderName}/${fileFromClient.originalname}`

    // 2a. In this server 1, read the contents of the file to upload to server 2
    // with fs.createReadStream(uploadedFilePath)
    // 2b. Append fs.createReadStream(uploadedFilePath) into a new FormData object key-value pair
    // with appropriate field for API on server 2
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('fieldWhereToSendFileTo', fs.createReadStream(uploadedFilePath))

    
    const API_POST_FILE_ENDPOINT = API_URL + `whatever/endpoint/to/post/to`

    // using Apar Adhikari's answer
    const fileResp = await axios.post(API_POST_FILE_ENDPOINT, form, {
        headers: {
          "id": apiToken,
          "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`
        }
      })
    //console logging info received from svr 2 into svr 1
    console.log(`POST/File to API - Status ${fileResp.status} - headers: ----${fileResp.headers}`) 
    

    // sending some response from svr 1 back to the client - including info from svr 2 axios response above (svr 2 -> svr 1 -> client)
    res.json({ message: "successful file upload!", 
    data: req.file,
    someOtherField: someOtherValue
    postFileStatus: fileResp.status,
    postFileHeaders: fileResp.headers,
    url: `http://localhost:${PORT}/${req.file.originalname}`})

  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ message: "error - ", error })
  }

})

// listen for requests :)
const listener = app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log("Express SVR - Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port)
})
```

Hope this explanation helps